# Remove Or from a list on LISP

Tags: list, lisp

I have to do this:

```
(or a w (or f r t) r (not p) (or (not p) a))

==> (a w f r t r (not p) (not p) a)
```

I've done this function:

```
(defun remove-or (x)
  (cond ((null x) x)
    ((atom x) x)
    ((and (listp x) (eq (first x) 'or)) (remove-or (cdr x)))
    (T (cons (remove-or (first x))
             (remove-or (rest x))))))
```

But the result is:

```
(or a w (or f r t) r (not p) (or (not p) a))

==> (a w (f r t) r (not p) ((not p) a))
```

How can I delete the "( )" ?

Comment: So the question actually is: how to flatten a tree, leaving (not ...) sub-lists?

Comment: Yes, but leaving ALL the notOR sublist... example... (or (not 1) (not 2) (3 4) (or (p ?X 123) r t y) t c) = ((not 1) (not 2) (3 4) (p ?x 123) r t y t c)

Comment: And how about (or or 1)? Should it become (), or (or 1)?

Comment: after a "or" there is a "(" ... my program changes a FBF in CNF .. your example can't exist in my program.. (or (or 1) 2) = (1 2)... (or (or 1)) = (1)

Comment: Do you know, that `or` could be a variable in common lisp? So it could be present in an arbitrary postion just like `a`, or `w` in your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check earlier for or-sublists like '((or ...) ...) so you can transform it into '(... ...).

The condition for it, simply is:

```
(and (listp lst) (listp (first lst))
     (eq (first (first lst)) 'or))
```

And the transformer:

```
(append (remove-or (rest (first lst)))
        (remove-or (rest lst)))
```

So this brings us to the your function with slightly modified third condition branch:

```
(defun remove-or (lst)
  (cond ((null lst) lst)
        ((atom lst) lst)
        ((and (listp lst) (listp (first lst))
              (eq (first (first lst)) 'or))
         (append (remove-or (rest (first lst)))
                 (remove-or (rest lst))))
        (t (cons (remove-or (first lst))
                 (remove-or (rest lst))))))
```

But this function will not handle a one special case: the or in the very beginning of the list: (**OR** a b (or (or c d) e)). But having an additional condition branch like `((and (listp x) (eq (first x) 'or)) (remove-or (cdr x)))` we will remove also `or`s acting like a variables: (a b **or** c **or**).

So this case must be handled separately, for instance:

```
(defun remove-or-head (lst)
   (remove-or (if (and (listp lst) (eq (first lst) 'or))
                  (rest lst)
                  lst))
```

To put it all together with recursive function hidden:

```
(defun remove-or (lst)
  (labels ((remove-or-rec (lst)
             (cond ((null lst) lst)
                   ((atom lst) lst)
                   ((and (listp lst) (listp (first lst))
                         (eq (first (first lst)) 'or))
                    (append (remove-or-rec (rest (first lst)))
                            (remove-or-rec (rest lst))))
                   (t (cons (remove-or-rec (first lst))
                          (remove-or-rec (rest lst)))))))
    (remove-or-rec (if (and (listp lst) (eq 'or (first lst)))
                       (rest lst)
                       lst))))
```